# One method dependent on another in a class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application which sends messages via Serial Bluetooth to a device which responds with an answer.

Now I am faced with the problem that methods are dependent on other methods.

For example, if I press the start button in my app, the message for starting the measurement has to be sent to the hardware device. But, the current settings of device are needed (a message has to be sent therefore).

The problem is now that I receive the settings just after the measurement has started due to asynchronicity (message for settings and measurement starting are sent nearly at the same time). Since the settings are required for a correct data packet processing, this results in wrong data packet handling.

To illustrate the problem, here is my current (shortened) code:

```
public class DeviceManager {
    // The current settings as single string value
    private String deviceSettings = "";

    // The last outgoing message
    private String lastOutgoingMessage = "";

    // The last incoming message
    private String lastIncomingMessage = "";

    // The measurement flag
    private boolean isMeasurementOn = false;

    // Local Bluetooth service
    private BluetoothService bluetoothService = null;

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothService
    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // Construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    handleResponse(readMessage, readBuf);
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // Construct a string from the buffer
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DeviceManager(BluetoothService bluetoothService) {
        // Initialize Bluetooth service
        this.bluetoothService = bluetoothService;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the responses of the device.
     *
     * @param responseString String - The response as string
     * @param responseArray byte[] - The response as bytes
     */
    public void handleResponse(String responseString, byte[] responseArray) {
        // Device settings requested
        if (lastOutgoingMessage.equals("wbagds\r")) {
            setDeviceSettings(responseString);
        }

        // Online measurement started (without sync)
        if (lastOutgoingMessage.equals("wbaom7\r") && lastIncomingMessage.equals("wbav10\r")) {
            // Set flag if not already set
            if (!isMeasurementOn) {
                isMeasurementOn = true;
            }
        }

        // Data packet received
        if (lastOutgoingMessage.equals("wbaom7\r") && isMeasurementOn) {
            // Let create data packet
            DataPacket dataPacket = dataPacketCreator.createDataPacket(responseArray, deviceSettings);
        }

        lastIncomingMessage = responseString;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the online measurement by sending the appropriate string to the device (requests the device settings first).
     */
    public void startOnlineMeasurement() {
        // Device settings are needed first
        requestDeviceSettings();

        lastOutgoingMessage = "wbaom7\r";
        sendMessageToDevice(lastOutgoingMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Requests the device settings by sending the appropriate string to the device.
     */
    public void requestDeviceSettings() {
        lastOutgoingMessage = "wbagds\r";
        sendMessageToDevice(lastOutgoingMessage);
    }
}
```

I have already tried different approaches such as wait/notify, callable/future.

However, I always ended up with the problem that I could not freeze the thread since I would not receive and could not handle the message anymore and therefore the future would never be fullfilled.

How could I manage this method dependency? Are there any obvious design problems in my application? Are there any obvious solutions with threads?

Comment: IMO the problem is not really clear. For me, it seems you have to follow an order when sending the messages (happened to me when working with BLE). If that's the case, just wait for the response before sending more information. You said you used wait/notify, how did you do it ? I think you have made it more easily with a state machine.

Comment: @JonZarate yes, I have to follow an order. I need the settings first, and then the measurement should be started.

Comment: You haven't anwered any of my questions.

Comment: @JonZarate indeed, state machine may be a something to think about;

Comment: @GhostCat you are right, I do not know why I didn't it that way :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your design.

It does not make sense to allow a user to start the measurement when you don't have the information yet to actually do that.

Thus: you should reverse your logic. First query the settings that you need later on, and only allow that button to be clicked when the settings are available.

In other words: simply avoid two async calls to overlap - make sure the "dependent" one takes place **after** the first one completed!